# How to get aadObjectId of Microsoft Personal Accounts which uses MS Teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We work on MS Teams bots. Each bot notification contains `aadObjectId` in request body by which we identify the user.

Sample Bot Request

```
{"name":"composeExtension/query","type":"invoke","timestamp":"2021-04-28T06:41:18.718Z","localTimestamp":"2021-04-28T12:11:18.718+05:30","id":"f:c3c988ef-b14b-b996-b3ec-cee22dbeb5ca","channelId":"msteams","serviceUrl":"https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/","from":{"id":"29:1FKDpJ_2YcIMpBd94h8BABBpkrv_RVSSeeJ3qh8U3djsypgk2lnJxbq_Sd4eUVFE2lHXBuUBMQ_se7QEvYzTbtQ","name":"Test Account","aadObjectId":"7812b15f-6462-44ef-a772-d9012c55bf1c"},"conversation":{"conversationType":"personal","tenantId":"4d4f9f3f-2553-430b-b86b-442be9306e29","id":"a:1W4nBEGebG_h5wTFEGuyFYXr0_vCYTvg3-lIZ9uKaPFiDZmtU5FIA2PH880C09mrtxbqEeIJ-sPQvwy0qfDhmTOPuEGRtkoT7NGS1eTBHBfjWXWFMRgOK5yzsNMlL6i0d"},"recipient":{"id":"28:97f33763-604f-89ae-40b3-719c55e66177","name":"Test Bot"},"entities":[{"locale":"en-GB","country":"GB","platform":"Web","timezone":"Asia/Calcutta","type":"clientInfo"}],"channelData":{"tenant":{"id":"4d4f9f3f-2553-430b-b86b-442be9306e29"},"source":{"name":"compose"}},"value":{"commandId":"Contacts","parameters":[{"name":"initialRun","value":"true"}],"queryOptions":{"skip":0,"count":25}},"locale":"en-GB","localTimezone":"Asia/Calcutta"}
```

During initial [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) we store the user id. We use OAuth2.0 and the below Microsoft Graph API to get the user id.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

We noticed that `id` returned in graph api and from bot framework is same for business(or Work) accounts.

However for personal accounts it is different

Sample Id's for reference

```
Work Account
From Graph API - id : 7812b15f-6462-44ef-a772-d9012c55bf1c
From Bot - aadObjectId : 7812b15f-6462-44ef-a772-d9012c55bf1c
```

```
Personal Account
From Graph API - id : 47268d7805746036
From Bot - aadObjectId : 6542b15f-7632-a772-44ef-d9012c55bf1c
```

So how to get the aadObjectId for personal users?

Comment: Is your personal account also added to the tenant?

Comment: Its not my personal account. It is any random users account

Comment: We have raised a bug on this and it is being tracked internally.